# Angular: How to get component child?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular10

I want to implement such component in Angular 10

```
<render-if-has-access [user]="user" [required-role]="admin">
    <h1>It top secret information</h1>
</render-if-has-access>
```

In new component **render-if-has-access** I have computed access. For true display child of this component in other case display empty.

My question is how can I use **render-if-has-access** child and pass it to component template?? I want to have reusable component (not always h1 tag be there)

Comment: Don't use a component for that. Build a structural directive instead. Then you can write something like this: `<h1 *requireRole="'admin'">secret information<h1>`. Pass the current user into the directive via a service and you have a pretty clean template. It should be noted though that information hidden like this should never be 'top secret' as anyone can still read it through development console. Use a backend service to provide really sensitive data.

Comment: Good point with this directive. I'll try in this way. Thanks :)